# Static Typing Hell

Tags: flutter, dart

My background is in Python where you treat everything as a duck, and free from defining types.
I recently started coding in Dart, and here I am facing these type casting issues.

What's wrong with the below code?

The `appendCsv` function takes a `List<List<dynamic>>` parameter, `getMarks` function returns a `List<dynamic>` list.

I want to call the `getMarks` in a loop and append all the lists to another list e.g the `x`. And then pass that list to the `appendCsv` function.

```
List<List<dynamic>> x = [];
var v = await etea.getMarks('809', 70740) as Iterable<List<dynamic>>;
x.addAll(v);
print(x);
print(x.runtimeType);
// x = x as List<List<dynamic>>;
print(x.runtimeType);

appendCsv('802', x);
```

I am getting these kinds of mix errors.

> type 'List<Iterable<String>>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<List<dynamic>>' in type cast

Answer (score 3):

If getMarks returns a List< dynamic> you just have to add it to x.

```
List<List<dynamic>> x = [];
for(what ever){
    List<dynamic> v = await etea.getMarks('809', 70740);
    x.add(v);
}
```

or even

```
List<List<dynamic>> x = [];
for(what ever){
    x.add(await etea.getMarks('809', 70740));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved my issue, thanks to [**@AntEdote**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12903702/antedote) as well as [**@coolhack7**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8297485/coolhack7)'s
[How to fix the error "'WhereIterable' is not a subtype of type 'List'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62972666/how-to-fix-the-error-whereiterableproducts-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listp)
The problem was in `getMarks` function it was returning a `List<WhereIterable<String>>` but I was treating it as `List<dynamic>`.
When you call `.where` on something, it returns a `WhereIterable` type, that's a stupid type name `WhereIterable` lol.
As described by **coolhack7**, I called `.toList()` on the `WhereIterable<String>` in `getMarks` and fixed the issue.